# Submitting an iphone 5 optimized app to app store

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

When I started creating my app in xcode, all of the view controllers in the main storyboard were the iphone 5 4 inch display. So I have finally completed my iphone 5 app, however, when I run the app on an iphone 4 simulator everything is overlapping and skewed. Do I have to completely duplicate the app and downscale all my views to the iphone 4 3.5 inch display, or do I just go ahead and submit the app as it is?

Comment: You must make it compatible with all listed devices, in this case, the closest you can get is iPhone 5 and iPhone 4S (using a specific bluetooth feature), so you must support the 3.5 inch display, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is either:

a) Turn on auto-layout in your storyboard file and make sure that the views are correctly laid out in both screen sizes. There is a button in the Storyboard that toggles the sizes:

[image]

b) figure out what the screen size is in code and modify their positions accordingly.

Option a) is the easiest one to do.

Comment: I have autolayout checked in storyboard, but what do you mean by laid out in both screen sizes? Do you mean make two views one 4 inch and one 3.5 inch?

Comment: No - I mean set the constraints on your views so that you views look good in both sizes. You can toggle the sizes in the Storyboard by using the button I've shown you.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks for the help